# 18.04 on MacBook Pro 8-2 is stuck on purple screen when booting

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, mac, macbook-pro

For the last 3 days I've been trying to install Ubuntu on a MacBookPro8-2 running High Sierra, in order to run an IOTA node.

I've tried Ubuntu 18.04 into a VM first and I quite like it.
I also can use it when booting from USB drive.

So, I started from a clean install of my MacBook Pro and followed all the tutorials I could find online. The one that appeared to me as the most Beginner friendly was this one, even though its for 16.04. I tried 16.04, but couldn't even install it (from https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733):

- Partitioning the SSD
- Creating Bootable USB Drive with Etcher
- Installing rEFInd
- Booting
- nomodeset to prevent getting stuck on Boot
- Installing from "Try Ubuntu without installing"
- Selecting FAT32 partition
- Installing

All these steps are going flawlessly. Then I Restart, and remove USB Drive. 
Upon restart I select my Ubuntu install in rEFInd and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But then I see a black screen with some text in the middle. It does not stay more than a fraction of a second so I can't read it. Then I get the Ubuntu purple background screen, without the logo or login prompt. And it just stays there forever.

I ended up having the same issue regardless which tutorial I was following. I even tried to install Ubuntu as my only OS, removing OS X, ending up with the same problem.

I've tried other post from Stack Exchange saying I should press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to access GRUB, but after I select Linux in rEFInd, the purple screen comes instantly. I never managed to get the grub screen.

Comment: Can access grub with [ESC] key... but still wasn't able to sort anything.

Comment: For some reason, this time adding nomodeset in GRUB allowed me access to the system. None that I've done it differently than the other tries.
I've read that being stuck on the purple background could be a result of a GPU issue, in my case Radeon. Posts also suggested to update the drivers.

In terminal I've run */sudo ubuntu-drivers devices/*, the only device that requires an update is my Wifi card. Same thing using the GUI tool.

Comment: Use a phone to record a video of the boot process then you can pause on the frame with the text messages to give us more info. Also does this comp have dual graphics cards and have you followed steps do use the integrated one in the boot process?

Comment: Can you boot a live CD/USB to look into the situation?  You said you were able to get into grub but unable to make any progress from there, is that correct?  If so, try to boot into recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following this site https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcdhJfe3aP8, it uses different software called Balena Etcher and downloads linux from the official site. It doesn't use rEFInd, so you have to hold option/alt, I have installed around ten linux's and this method has never failed.

EDIT:
Plug in flash drive. Wipe flash drive. download ubuntu here "https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.3&architecture=amd64". Then download balena etcher here. "https://www.balena.io/etcher/". Next, open balena etcher and select the iso image that you downloaded from ubuntu.com, then select flash drive and hit start. When you reboot, hold the option/alt key and wait until a boot screen comes up, select UEFI and hit enter.
EDIT: I wouldn't use rEFInd, because it is manufactured by less people and is updated less often, it also compatible with less computer hardware. I would uninstall that and just hit alt/option key on reboot to enter grub.

Comment: A link that is only a youtube video with no details is not considered an answer. What about later when that video may be gone?

Comment: Balena Etcher is mentioned in the question.